# Lenovo x1 carbon (gen1) battery life

Tags: laptop, power-management, lenovo, battery

I'm using an Lenovo x1 carbon (gen1) and have Ubuntu 14.04 and tlp installed. I'm really dissapointed about the battery life. Some people claim to have 6 hours (https://dague.net/2014/01/11/thinkpad-x1-carbon-awesome-linux-laptop/) and even sometimes 8 hours ([Thinkpad X1 Carbon - terrible battery life on Raring](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286490/thinkpad-x1-carbon-terrible-battery-life-on-raring)).

I usually get 3 hours with reduced screen brightness (3 tips) with moderate usage like browsing the web, looking at pdfs and doing some programming. What battery life do you get and please post your powertop otherwise I can't believe those 6 or 8 hours...
Here is mine:

```
The battery reports a discharge rate of 10.7 W
The estimated remaining time is 3 hours, 22 minutes

Summary: 627.5 wakeups/second,  13.9 GPU ops/seconds, 0.0 VFS ops/sec and 12.1%

Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
3.55 W     60.0%                      Device         Display backlight
708 mW      8.0 ms/s     138.4        Interrupt      PS/2 Touchpad / Keyboard
584 mW     13.4 ms/s     106.0        Process        /opt/google/chrome-unstab
575 mW      3.1 pkts/s                Device         Network interface: eth0 (
370 mW     21.3 ms/s      59.3        Process        compiz
319 mW      0.1 pkts/s                Device         nic:vmnet8
```

So usually my display, chrome and wifi is draining my battery most. Further I use my laptop extensively since one year and already lost 18.2% of my battery capacity  (37.6 Wh left).

The keyboard uses that much power since I upgraded to 14.04. Anybody else noticed this?

Thanks!

Comment: yeah ubuntu 14.04 has somewhat less batterylife than other os

Comment: I'm not comparing to any other OS. I'm always talking about Ubuntu. Battery life was the same on Ubuntu 13.10 too.

Comment: I have experienced only with 12.04 and it was also draining a good amt of battery in no time