# Unable to install Ubuntu on Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon 4th Generation

Tags: system-installation, thinkpad

#### General Goal

I've spend about 2 full days on this issue by now. And my goal sounds fairly simple: I want to install Ubuntu on my new Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon 4th Generation.

#### Problem

After booting from the USB stick with Ubuntu 14.04 or 15.10 I get a black screen after selecting ***install*** from the menu. The only response is a blinking cursor int he upper left corner. Settings like ***nomodeset*** etc. do not solve this problem.

Just to check if there is a fundamental error with my hardware I installed Windows 10, which was successful.

Starting the Ubuntu installation with the grub verbose setting, I saw that the installation stops at the line: 
*intel_pstate: HWP enabled* 
Searching the internet on this, I stumbled upon [a Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/410haw/yoga_260_wont_boot_ubuntu_with_kernel_4244_but/) which seems to match my problem.

Does anybody have an idea, how to solve this?

#### These are my Hardware Specifications:

- Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon 4th Generation
- Processor Clock Speed: 2.6 GHz
- Turbo Boost: 3.4 GHz
- Processor Family: Intel Core i7
- Processor Model: i7-6600U
- CPU Cores: 2
- Cache: 2 × 256 KB L2, 4 MB L3
- Motherboard Chipset: Integrated with CPU
- Intel vPro Technology: yes
- Trusted Platform Module (TPM): yes
- Installed RAM: 16 GB
- Video Card: Intel HD 520

Comment: It's an old thread, but is there any inspiration for you here? "[Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon support](http://askubuntu.com/q/199199/38585)"

Comment: Thank you for you comment David, but this is not the same issue.

Comment: I've now also tried BETA Ubuntu 16.04, which also gets stuck at:
intel_pstate: HWP enabled

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Solution

So the very problem was that for some reason, intel_pstate is not supported. As explained in the [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/410haw/yoga_260_wont_boot_ubuntu_with_kernel_4244_but/). The solution was to deactivate intel_pstate in the kernel boot parameters.

What I did not get, was how to modify the boot parameters manually for the Ubuntu Startup-USB. This is done by entering the F6 menu and exit the menu right away. Now there is a new line visible on the screen. This line can be edited by pressing **e** add the command *intel_pstate=no_hwp* (for example after *quiet*). Now you can install Ubuntu. To be able to reboot after the installation, you need to alter the kernel boot parameters via grub [explained here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters).
Once you logged into Ubuntu you can now alter this setting permanently [also explained here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters).

Good luck!